# Jupyter notebook on Docker - permission denied

Tags: python, docker, jupyter

I have a Docker container running on a remote computer, which is mapped to port 3000 and root folder **/data**:
When accessing root folder with Jupyter notebook, I get the following error message:

> Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in
> _execute result = await result File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in
> wrapper yielded = ctx_run(next, result) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
> line 112, in get path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py",
> line 437, in get model = self._dir_model(path, content=content) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py",
> line 311, in _dir_model for name in os.listdir(os_dir):
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data'

Other directories work, except root (i.e. I can access /data/abc/). Notebooks work.
Notebook ver.: 4.4.0
Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

One of the other users on the network made some modifications and messed up permission rights, it looks like it can be done like this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /data
```

and the *Permission denied* warning disappears..